# How do I determine reflection matrix over a line through the origin with direction vector $\vec{v}=\left(a,b\right) ^{T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I don't understand this really good and couldnt find anything helpful on internet. I only found in book the following: A is the matrix with reflection over line through the origin with direction vector $\left(\cos(\frac{\alpha }{2} ) , \sin(\frac{\alpha }{2} ) \right) ^{T}$
$A=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha ) & \sin(\alpha ) \\ \sin(\alpha )  & -\cos(\alpha )    \end{pmatrix}$
I'm not sure how to connect this from book to solve it, because there is another direction vector.

Comment: I would guess that the simplest approach is to note that the reflection takes $(a,b)^T$ to itself and $(b,-a)^T$ to $(-b,a)^T$. The mapping is linear, so this should be enough information.

Answer (score 0):

From prior experience, the reflection matrix can be written as a linear combination of the identity matrix and a suitable projection matrix. With this in mind, we let $R=AI+Bvv^T$ and seek to determine $A,B$. (Technically $vv^T$ is only proportional to a projection matrix, but this can be absorbed into the definition of $B$ without issue.)

First, note that the vector $v$ pointing along the line of reflection should be mapped to itself; on the other hand, the vector $u=(b,-a)^T$ is perpendicular to $v$ and therefore should be mapped to its reflection through the origin. Together, this yields 
\begin{align}
v&=Rv=Av+Bv(v^T v)=(A+B v^T v)v \\ -u&=Ru=Au+Bv(v^T u)=Au
\end{align} which solves to $(A,B)=(-1,2/v^T v)$. Hence $R=2(vv^T/v^T v)-I$.

The above is valid for any vector $v$. But if this is a direction vector i.e. $v^Tv=1,$ then $R=2v v^T-I$. (Note that $vv^T$ is now a true projection matrix since $(v v^T)^2=v v^T$). This is the case mentioned in the problem statement, and one can use double-angle identities to confirm that the matrix $R$ quoted above indeed coincides with $2 v v^T-I$.

Comment: The above approach is entirely algebraic. But a geometric approach is also illuminating; for that, I suggest reviewing how one projects a given vector onto a line, and try relate that to the problem of reflection across that line.